# Sluggish Gnome 42 desktop (worse than on 6 year old system) - Need help to troubleshoot

Tags: fedora, gnome, intel, wayland

I'm trying to find out why the performance of a newer and faster computer (NUC11) is so much worse than an older (NUC6). I would expect the NUC11 to blow the older system out of the water, but quite the opposite is the case.

With performance I mean the "subjective Gnome responsiveness", which I could luckily quantify by running the `glmark2` benchmark which shows that the old NUC6's score is orders of magnitude higher (2901) than the NUC11's (187). I don't know if that's a good methodology to quantify the perceived system responsiveness (speed of windows opening, hot corner, scrolling lag, etc), but let's assume for a moment it is (happy to run other benchmarks).

Here are some facts about the systems. I tried to make them as equal as possible for comparison. Both run Fedora 36, latest Gnome 42/Wayland, I ran the benchmark under same kernels (5.17.14-300.fc36.x86_64), the driver they are using is the Intel `i915` (same version as far I can tell via `modinfo i915`)

#### NUC6

- CPU: i7-6770HQ (Q1'2016), built-in: Intel Iris Pro Graphics 580
- 32GB RAM (speed 2133 MT/s)

#### NUC11

- CPU: i7-1165G7 (Q3'20), built-in: Intel Iris Xe Graphics + Discrete Geforce RTX 2060 (Nouveau nv166 driver)
- 16GB RAM (speed 3200 MT/s)

Granted, the NUC11 has half the RAM (but it's never fully allocated during the benchmark or when I run Gnome), but that's all I can see where the NUC6 has a leg up. In every other aspect, the NUC11 should by far outperform the NUC6, in particular since it has a discrete GPU to help rendering the Gnome desktop (I don't know if that's how Wayland works, but I would think so). I can't turn off the discrete GPU unfortunately to make the systems more alike (to eliminate any possible conflict between the two GPUs). As a side note, the NVidia scores ~800 glmark2 points which also doesn't sound plausible when comparing it with the 6 year old NUC6's internal GPU which scored 2901.

Something is slamming the brakes in the NUC11, but so far, I couldn't find anything. Is there anything else anyone can think of that I could try to troubleshoot why the NUC11 is so much slower than the much older NUC6? Any help, pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try Xorg for a change? I know people are obsessed with Wayland but it's still not ready IMO specially not with NVIDIA. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/_images/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session_2.png Also make sure NVIDIA drivers are properly installed. Here's a specific Linux NVIDIA forum for such questions: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: For Xorg, the benchmark scores about the same (`184`) for the integrated Intel GPU and  the RTX score actually went down (`589`). I'm going to try out with the official proprietary drivers...

Comment: Installing the `515.48.07` Nvidia driver and removing the nouveau drivers brought a score of `11123` which is a noticeable improvement in terms of responsiveness.

Comment: However there are a few odd things now. (1) I don't have a Wayland option in GDM any more, the score is Xorg (I might have removed that when uninstalling a previously failed Nvidia driver before trying it again now). (2) GDM boots up in some weird colours (I would say 8 bit colour depth, but it changes every time - hardly readable font) - I "fix" this by hot-plugging another monitor (`ALT+F2 r` doesn't restore normal colours) and I have now "NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 2060 / NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 2060" showing (twice) in my GNOME settings/about screen where there was the Intel GPU mentioned before.